# Using VBA To Convert A Column of Formulas From Relative To Fixed Reference

Tags: vba, excel

First off, apologies if this is a silly question. I'm new to VBA. I searched online for this answer but couldn't find it.

I'm trying to convert a long column of formulas from relative references to absolute cell references. Essentially, I would like VBA to go through the column, select a cell, "hit F4" and then move to the next cell.

I recorded this action in VBA and got the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Worksheet'!R11C9"
Range("G5212").Select
```

My question is what in this command is the equivalent of hitting F4? I'm not good at reading VBA and I'm trying to understand this. And, of course, if I'm going about this completely the wrong way please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: sorry i'm lost, but can you simplify further what you want to achieve?

Comment: @L42 While I most certainly could be wrong he definatly *seems* to states he is trying to simulate the pressing of `F4` in a cell, relative references to absolute cell references (`A1` to `$A$1`) but for an entire column.

Comment: Yep, exactly what user214 said!

Comment: @user2140261 yep i think you're pretty close. so i leave it you :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim LastCell As Range

Set LastCell = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Range("G1", LastCell).Formula = Application.ConvertFormula _
(Formula:=Range("G1", LastCell).Formula, FromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
ToReferenceStyle:=xlA1, ToAbsolute:=xlAbsolute)
```

Change your column as needed. I assumed `G` based on question.